# Salesforce - List has no rows returned

Tags: salesforce, apex

When i checked in Database the same query returning 18 rows, but in my Apex class it is retuning zero rows as in

```
 List<Account> accList=[SELECT Name,Id,ShippingStreet,ShippingState,ShippingCountry,ShippingCity,ShippingPostalCode
                           FROM Account];
 System.debug('accList size:'+accList.size());
```

Please check their snapshots attached below,[image]

[image]

Please tell me the error happening in my code.

Comment: Did the apex and SOQL query run under the same user? I guess that the most possible issue is if apex runs `with sharing` under restricted user and SOQL runs under sysadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved the issue.  I am running those statements in a apex Test class, I forget to include the insert statements for the coresponding records, after adding the below statements to my code,

```
    Account acc=new Account(Name='test',ShippingStreet='Test address');
    insert acc;
```

Resolved my issue.